# ora-00955: name is already used by an existing object during a select of a view

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, wcf, view

I have a oracle view that look like this (that's my client view and he does not want me to have access to the table)

```
public class V_UT_ALIAS
{
    public int PRIMARYKEY { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

For my tests I create a table with the same information as the view.
I have a context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(new OracleConnection(nameOrConnectionString), true)
    {
    }
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {
    }


    public virtual IDbSet<V_UT_ALIAS> Alias { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooViewConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class FooViewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<V_UT_ALIAS>
{
    public FooViewConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("V_UT_ALIAS","THECLIENTUSER");
        this.HasKey(t => t.PRIMARYKEY);
    }
}
```

When I use the linq query

```
var test = (from patate in Context.Alias select patate.PRIMARYKEY).ToList();
```

I got the exception in the title, but if I change the FooViewConfiguration Table to my mockup table everything work.

I also try the direct call with Context.Database.SqlQuery and it's the same error.

Do I miss something like a config for the view to make sure entity framework does not try to create the view but use the one already created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off your Database Initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thank you, someone I'm working with say it did not work. But I still try it (after reading your message) and it's working.... -_-